# Multiple MATCH's to Transactional REST API

Tags: transactions, neo4j

I started developing a Neo4j 2.0 client and when I reach to the transactional endpoint there is something I'm not sure about:

Which is the best option when using multiple MATCHes (no creates, no updates) regarding to performance? I don't known how is this implemented in the neo4j internals...:

- Use /transaction/commit multiple times (does this create one transaction witch each one or identifies that it is not necessary?)
- Create a transaction (with the first MATCH) and then use /transaction/x/ with each finishing with a weird commit with the last statement?

Imagine that I cannot put multiple statements in one request because I need to pack data with in-memory state in order to do the next query.

Probably the first one it's enough but...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most efficient:

- Multiple queries directly to /transaction/commit (creating a new transaction each one?)

It depends on the usage though, if decisions for the following queries are made based on the results of previous ones then you'll probably want to support multiple requests within a single tx.